# How to use Shopify Graphql ProductVariantsBulkInput

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to bulk update the price on multiple product variants at once. [I'm just copying the "interactive" example from Shopify's page](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/products-and-collections/productvariantsbulkupdate)

All I did was copy and paste the code and put in my own id's. And of course it does not work.

It looks like this:

```
mutation productVariantsBulkUpdate($variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!, $productId: ID!) {
  productVariantsBulkUpdate(variants: $variants, productId: $productId) {
    product {
      cursor
    }
    productVariants {
      cursor
    }
    userErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

With Variables like this:

```
{
  "variants": [
    {
      id:  "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/39369514385591",
      price: "50.00"
    }
  ],
  "productId": "gid://shopify/Product/6591908577463"
}
```

I'm getting this error:
`Variables are invalid JSON: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 30.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK for me. (with some quick tweaks)

I tweaked the request a little since the `cursor` is not present in the product/variant object, don't know why Shopify has not updated the example in their docs.

```
mutation productVariantsBulkUpdate($variants: [ProductVariantsBulkInput!]!, $productId: ID!) {
  productVariantsBulkUpdate(variants: $variants, productId: $productId) {
    product {
      id
    }
    productVariants {
      id
      price
    }
    userErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

So try to fix the query and remove the `cursor` object and check if you are using the proper end-point since the bulk operation is available in the unstable version only if I'm not mistaken.

See the image below showing that the response is OK for me.

[image]

Comment: yep you were right on all the fronts! Plus only the unstable version of the API supports this.